# How to use underscore.js in WordPress Admin

Tags: wp-admin, wp-enqueue-script, underscore

I am trying to use underscore in my WordPress Admin. This is what I have done: I enqueue a script in the very end of the page, like so:

```
function load_admin_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script( "my-admin", get_template_directory_uri() . "/assets/scripts/admin.js", array('jquery', 'wp-util'), null, true );
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_admin_scripts');
```

...then in the script file, I am at the moment only trying this:

```
console.log( jQuery ); // is defined
console.log( underscore ); // ReferenceError: underscore is not defined(…)
```

Can anyone point me to the solution for this?

Comment: What creative things are you doing with underscore.js in wordpress?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to you chrome **JavaScript** console window and write `_.VERSION`. Then press Enter. It will return you the version of the included **Underscore JS**. Also it will make sure that **Underscore JS** is included or enqueued. And **Underscore JS** is include in **WordPress** admin by default. You don't need to enqueue it. Just use it as you use any where else.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you enqueue underscore js on theme function.php

```
/**
 * Proper way to enqueue scripts and styles.
 */
function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'underscore' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts' );
```

Then you can check underscore version on browser console

```
console.log(_.VERSION)
```